# Beta regression using categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, beta-regression

I have been asked to do beta-regression for my data. The independent variable is categorical (there are three treatments A, B and C). The dependent variable is the proportion of time an animal is sleeping. I used the following equation:model1 <- gamlss(CI_frac ~ factor(Treatment), data =df,family=BEINF) for the model. How do I do pairwise comparisons between Treatment A, B, and C?

Comment: I would suggest using contrasts for this purpose, which gamlss provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `multcomp` package, even though the standard `linfct = mcp(...)` functionality for specifying the contrast matrix does not work. However, it is possible to set up the desired contrast matrix by hand.

See the following discussion for a worked example for `gam` objects from `mgcv`. The analogous strategy can also be used for `gamlss` objects:
[Correcting for multiple pairwise comparisons with GAM objects {mgcv} in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376237/correcting-for-multiple-pairwise-comparisons-with-gam-objects-mgcv-in-r)

Comment: Would the package emmen work ?

Comment: If you mean `emmeans`: According to its NEWS page, `emmeans` provides support for `gamlss` objects: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/news/news.html

Comment: Is it okay to use emmeans package if your data is not normal or has hetegenous variance?

Comment: I think `emmeans` leverages (asymptotic) normality of the parameter estimates, not of the actual observations. So provided that you have specified an appropriate model that can capture the non-normality and heteroscedasticity, this holds for many models.